# IME_ACTION_NEXT doesn't work on the last EditText of my layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a vertical `LinearLayout` with a list of `EditText`s. Android automatically handle for me the IME action: `IME_ACTION_NEXT` for all the `EditText`s except for the last one, for which it is `IME_ACTION_DONE`.

Now, I want to programmatically set the IME action of the last `EditText` to be `IME_ACTION_NEXT` as well, and also set the ID of the next `EditText` to focus on (the first one, to allow the user to "loop" on all the fields). But when I do:

```
int firstEditTextId = ...
valueView.setNextFocusDownId(firstEditTextId);
lastEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NAVIGATE_NEXT);
lastEditText.setImeActionLabel("Go to the first one, please", EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

it doesn't work: on my Android 7.1 device the on-screen keyboard still shows the "Done" icon. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set this to your last EditText:

```
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/firstEditText"
```

And you could try to use

```
lastEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
```

instead of

```
lastEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NAVIGATE_NEXT);
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: IME ACTION NEXT only works if both fields are visible AFTER the soft keyboard is launched.